# Adding Hyperlinks to a PDF - Table of contents using Python

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to add hyperlinks to Table of Contents section in a PDF using Python. The hyperlink should point to the existing PDF.

I used PyPDF2 library to add bookmarks and it works well. However, did not find an easy way to add hyperlinks.

This is what I am using to add bookmarks. Can this be tweaked to add hyperlinks instead? Thanks!

```
pip install PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

pdf_object = open(path,"rb") #rb stands for read binary
output = PdfFileWriter()

input = PdfFileReader(pdf_object)
input_numpages = input.getNumPages()

# copy the input file
for i in range(input_numpages):
output.addPage(input.getPage(i)) #insert page in the output file

parent_1 = output.addBookmark('Chapter 1', 2) # add parent bookmark
parent_2 = output.addBookmark('Chapter 2', 4) # add parent bookmark

outputstream = open(path) #creating result
output.write(outputstream) #writing to result pdf
outputstream.close() #closing result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try addLink(pagenum, pagedest, rect, border=None, fit='/Fit', *args) instead of addBookmark()

https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileWriter.html